# I have an issue with Javascript menu bar

Tags: javascript

I have a menu bar that works well using IE and, on some systems, Google Chrome. However, I recently purchased a Dell computer and the menu bar will not work. When I mouse over for a drop-down, I simply see javascript:; on the task bar. Can anyone assist me? Thank you. - Dr. David A. Dutcher

Comment: Folks cannot help you without a link to the specific web page or including the relevant HTML/CSS/javascript in your question.  Without that, all we're left to do is offer wild guesses.

Answer (score 0):

Got a link?

Sounds like you have javascript disabled on your browser. But cant be sure.